# Java Casting Problem

Tags: java, generics, casting

Why isn't a `Map<String,List<SomeBean>>` castable to `Map<String,List<?>>`?

What I'm doing now is this:

```
Map<String, List<SomeBean>> fromMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<SomeBean>>();

/* filling in data to fromMap here */

Map<String,List<?>> toMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<?>>();
for (String key : fromMap.keySet()) {
    toMap.put(key, fromMap.get(key));
}
```

In my opinion there should be a way around this manual transformation, but I can't figure out how. Any Ideas?

Comment: it works on my JDK 6 Eclipse..

Comment: I would be very surprised if the cast worked in your Eclipse. Are you talking about the given snippet?

Comment: yeah, I meant the snippet works..

Comment: @Bozho: Shure, because that was my work-around. But this was what I tried, and that doesn't compile: `Map<String,List<?>> toMap = (Map<String,List<?>>) new Map<String, List<SomeBean>>()`. ~Chris

Comment: Gilad Bracha's [Generics in the Java Programming Language] (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) paper is an excellent source of information on generics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cast is invalid because in Map<String,List<?>> you can put List<String> and List<WhatEver>, but not in Map<String, List<SomeBean>>.

For instance:

```
    //List<SomeBean> are ok in both lists
    fromMap.put("key", new ArrayList<SomeBean>());
    toMap.put("key", new ArrayList<SomeBean>());

    //List<String> are ok in Map<String,List<?>>, not in Map<String, List<SomeBean>>
    fromMap.put("key", new ArrayList<String>()); //DOES NOT COMPILE
    toMap.put("key", new ArrayList<String>());
```

To simplify your code, you may use the appropriate constructor to simplify your code:

```
    Map<String, List<SomeBean>> fromMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<SomeBean>>();
    Map<String,List<?>> toMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<?>>(fromMap);
```

Comment: Aahh.. Now it does make sense! Thank you very much for you explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Not realy an answer to your question, but as an extra: I would not use keyset here... If you want to iterate through all the elements of a map, use the entrySet() method. Its faster because it does not require the key-value lookup for each element.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<SomeBean>> entry : fromMap.entrySet()) {
  toMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to, you could cast to a raw Map (but what you want is not type safe):

```
Map<String,List<?>> toMap = (Map) new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Comment: I would suggest this if you are sure about the map types. It's ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

When assigning to a Map, where K and V are not wildcard parameters, the Map being assigned must have exactly the same K and V. In your case, V must be exactly `List<?>`.

The workaround it to use a wildcard V.

`Map<String, ? extends List<?>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();`
Because the V you are assigning to is a wildcard, the V being assigned must only be assignable to V (rather than being exactly V).